# Using provenance hash function for NFT project

Tags: solidity, nft

Just a newbie to the Solidity world who really wants to understand the "provenance hash" for an NFT project.

I saw this in number of projects and tried to use it on Remix. I get that it proves that metadata is preset prior to the minting but I'm not sure **how to use this.**

I can input a string on Remix and see that provenancehash appears when I call it. But how does this prove that the metadata is preset?

Thanks a lot for your help!

```
string public PROVENANCE;
function setProvenance(string memory provenance) public onlyOwner {
  PROVENANCE = provenanceHash;
}
```

You can also see the full script here.
https://github.com/lee-injae/Solidity/blob/master/Project_Upload.sol

Thank you for the help!

Comment: See here https://medium.com/coinmonks/the-elegance-of-the-nft-provenance-hash-solution-823b39f99473. It is used to prove that there will be no metadata manipulation after minting.